# Json view formating in drupal

Tags: javascript, php, drupal

I created a json data using views but in my body field I am getting unwanted " \n \n " in the json and I also missing the URL's for images added in the body field and links to the some text also missing.

[image: Data from the node]

[image: Json from View]

Comment: Do you see those "\n" (or new lines) when you edit that content from back-end?

Comment: Which editor are you using ?